# Operational Error 1054 Unknown Column

Tags: operationalerror

```
class ProjectTimeAllocation(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    project_id = models.ForeignKey(Projects, models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='pj_id', blank=True, null=True)
    project_manager_id = models.ForeignKey(ProjectManagers, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    hours = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    week = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)


    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'project_time_allocation'
```

views.py

```
def timeallocation(request, project_manager_id):
    #time_list = ProjectTimeAllocation.objects.order_by('-id')
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ProjectTimeAllocationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            #post.project_manager_id = project_manager_id
            post.save()
            messages.success(request, "Updated Time!")
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/dashboard/')
    else:
        form = ProjectTimeAllocationForm()
    return render(request, 'dashboard/timeallocation.html', {'form':form})
```

forms.py

```
class ProjectTimeAllocationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    week = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget())



    class Meta:
        model = ProjectTimeAllocation       
        fields = (
            'hours',
            'week',
            'project_manager_id',
            'project_id',
            )
        widgets = {

        }
        labels = {

        }
```

I get an operational error (1054, "Unknown column 'project_id_id' in field list.  I don't understand where the extra _id is coming from?  I have tried clearing the migrations and making new migrations.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that django appends _id on ForeignKeys and thus I had to remove _id from my column name in the model and in the form and then django appended it back on when it generated the sql insert statement and the problem is now resolved.